# Can I dynamically detect the Zend framework in the include path?

Tags: zend-framework, include-path, php-include

I'm developing a plugin for WordPress that will add additional functionality if the Zend framework is available, but the functionality added is not great enough to justify the user installing the framework if it does not already exist.

My question is, is there any good way to detect if Zend exists? Obviously I can use `get_include_path()` to return whatever the include path is, but beyond that I'm not sure. I could use regexes to determine if the phrase `zend` appears in the paths, but that seems unreliable at best (more thinking false positives than false negatives, but I think both have a potential if people haven't used the default path).

If I have to resort to this regex, I can always trap the errors as they come and proceed from there, but if there's a better way then that would be useful to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way:

```
if (stream_resolve_include_path('Zend/Version.php')) {
    // ZF found
}
```

but I would question why you need to do this. If your plugin needs to be coded to work without the framework, what do you gain by using it if it's there? Seems like this would just complicate your code.

Comment: Thanks, Tim. The code will provide basic functionality on any system, but will enhance itself if the option exists. It's nothing major, but the added work (setting a zend flag and checking on execution) won't really add any real complexity to the code, only one if/else. Like I said, it's minor.

Comment: One should mention this requires at least PHP 5.3.2 so you may add this to your requirements documentation of your plugin ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is somewhat easy:

```
$zfPresent = (bool) stream_resolve_include_path("Zend/Application.php")
```

If the file could be found inside the include paths `stream_resolve_include_path()` will return it's absoulte path - if not it will return false.

So if it is found the framework is definatly there.

Only grain of salt for some people: It requires at least PHP 5.3.2

See: http://php.net/manual/de/function.stream-resolve-include-path.php

If the PHP version does not allow you to use the above solution:

Try something like this:

```
set_error_handler(function($code, $text, $file, $line) {
    // Handle zend not present    

    /* So that internal error handling won't be executed */
    return true;
});

include("Zend/Application.php");

restore_error_handler();
```

I don't think it's really elegant but it should be somewhat reliable in detecting Zend. Another way may be something like:

```
function checkForZf()
{
    $includePaths = array_merge(explode(PATH_SEPARATOR, get_include_path(), array($myAppsLib));

    foreach($includePaths as $path) {
        if (file_exists($path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'Zend' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'Application.php') {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This should be also somewhat reliable but file actions are performance expensive. You may test it out in regards to performance or store the state somewhere after first detection so it does not need to run on every request.